# WordPress: How do I add more than one taxonomies in a custom post post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I have created a Custom Post Type called `user-story`. The `$args` looks like this:

```
$args = array(
   'labels' => $labels,
   'hierarchical' => true,
   'description' => 'description',
   'taxonomies' => array('category', 'story-type', 'genre'),
   'show_ui' => true,
   'show_in_menu' => true,
   'menu_position' => 5,
   'menu_icon' => 'http://webmaster.webmastersuccess.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/pencil.png',
   'public' => true,
   'has_archive' => true,
   'query_var' => true,
   'capability_type' => 'post',
   'supports' => $supports,
   'rewrite' => $rewrite,
   'register_meta_box_cb' => 'add_story_metaboxes' );

register_post_type('user_story', $args);
```

The problem is in line `'taxonomies' => array('category', 'story-type', 'genre'),`. I cannot see my taxonomies `story-type` and `genre` in **Add New Story** page in admin. Only `category` is showing up.

Both `story-type` and `genre` are custom taxonomies. I deactivated CPT plugin (`user_story`) and then reactivated it. But still above custom taxonomies are not coming up.

Both custom taxonomies are registered through plugins and they are visible in Admin menu. Terms registered under these taxonomies are also showing up in their respective list pages.

Screenshot-1: List of terms registered in taxonomy `story-type`

[image]

Screenshot-2: List of terms registered in taxonomy `genre`

[image]

Screenshot-3: Add New Story page - none of the above taxonomies other than only the built-in taxonomy `category` is listed

[image]

I referenced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864572/in-wordpress-how-do-you-register-built-in-taxonomies-with-custom-post-types-in-c).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This one should help:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/

Place this code in your functions.php file and custom taxonomies should be added to your custom post type.

```
<?php
add_action( 'init', 'create_user_story_tax' );

function create_user_story_tax() {

    /* Create Genre Taxonomy */
    $args = array(
        'label' => __( 'Genre' ),
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'genre' ),
        'hierarchical' => true,
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'genre', 'user-story', $args );
    
    /* Create Story Type Taxonomy */
    $args = array(
            'label' => __( 'Story Type' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'story-type' ),
            'hierarchical' => true,
        );

    register_taxonomy( 'story-type', 'user-story', $args );
    
}
?>
```

Comment: Awesome! So basically in order to bring custom taxonomies in custom post types I have to tell WordPress specifically where I want to show them. In this process I can also bring in same custom taxonomy in multiple CPTs too.

Comment: Thanks for the snippet. I got a syntax error because there was a missing ; right before register_taxonomy.